# Bash Script to Rebuild Nginx w/ Custom Modules

Tags: nginx, bash, apt, perl

I'm trying to write a script that will build Nginx from sources with custom modules... I'd like to do it in a clean manner that doesn't require updating version numbers after a new release.

What I've got so far looks like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt && cd /opt

# Fetch Module(s)
sudo git clone https://github.com/AirisX/nginx_cookie_flag_module.git

# Update Apt Repositories
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
sudo sed -i "s/# deb-src/deb-src/" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list
sudo apt-get update

# Fetch Nginx Sources/Dependencies
sudo mkdir -p /opt/rebuildnginx && cd /opt/rebuildnginx
sudo apt-get dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get source -y nginx
sudo apt-get build-dep -y nginx

# Add Module(s) To Nginx Rules
sudo perl -p0i -e 's/^(full_configure_flags(?:.*?\\\n)+.*)/$1 \\\n                        --add-dynamic-module=\/opt\/nginx_cookie_flag_module\n/m' /opt/rebuildnginx/nginx-1.12.1/debian/rules
```

I have two issues with this currently, both pertaining to the last line.

1. Functionality: It has a hard-coded version in the path... how could I rewrite this to get the path automatically?
2. Aesthetics: The last line is rather long... how could I shorten it? I tried breaking it up into variables but I don't have a very strong understanding of BASH or Perl and was unable to get it to work in any of my several attempts.

Answer (score 0):

## lots of sudo's

To get rid of the `sudo` on every line consider [asking for root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746350/request-root-privilege-from-within-a-script/748362).

## don't repeat yourself

Your `/opt/rebuildnginx` directory is used in 3 different places.  It should be a variable.  I'd use `BUILDBASE` for the variable name or something similar.

## hard-coded path

I thought you might be able to find this from `apt-cache` but those versions look different than yours.  If you haven't run this script before for previous versions of nginx this should work:

```
VERSION=`ls -d nginx*`                                                            
RULES="/opt/rebuildnginx/$VERSION/debian/rules"
```

Here's an example of doing that:

```
$ VERSION=`ls -d nginx*`
$ echo $VERSION
nginx-1.12.1
$ RULES="/opt/rebuildnginx/$VERSION/debian/rules"
$ echo $RULES
/opt/rebuildnginx/nginx-1.12.1/debian/rules
```

To make this reliable you could `rm -rf /opt/rebuildnginx` each time.  You probably also need to check for the `git clone`d directory's existence before cloning to make your script re-runnable.

## shortening last line

There are a few things we can do for your last line.  To start let's split it up into a few lines:

```
sudo perl -p0i \
  -e 's/^(full_configure_flags(?:.*?\\\n)+.*)/$1 \\\n                        --add-dynamic-module=\/opt\/nginx_cookie_flag_module\n/m' \
  /opt/rebuildnginx/nginx-1.12.1/debian/rules
```

Then we can use the filename variable from the previous section:

```
sudo perl -p0i \
  -e 's/^(full_configure_flags(?:.*?\\\n)+.*)/$1 \\\n                        --add-dynamic-module=\/opt\/nginx_cookie_flag_module\n/m' \
  "$RULES"
```

You could turn also the Perl expression into a double quoted string and build it up with variables, but I think that would be messier and harder to debug.  Sticking with the single quoted string for that is a good bet and at least now the filename isn't hidden past the edge of your screen.

I doubt you need all of that whitespace before `--add-dynamic-module`.  If not it is needed get rid of a few spaces.  Or maybe use `\t\t\t\t` instead of the long bunch of spaces if tabs are acceptable.